# AJAX Keeps refreshing content rendering my buttons useless

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I wonder why AJAX keeps making calls, this way its so hard to press a button and the site is not functional like this... : http://buycheapvaporizer.com/products.php

My JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
product();

function product(){
    $.ajax({
        url :   "productloader2.php",
        method: "POST",
        data    :   {getProduct:1},
        success :   function(data){
            $("#get_product").html(data);
        },
        complete: function() {
            setTimeout(product, 10000);
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: `setTimeout(product, 10000)` is recalling `product` after 10 seconds

Answer (score 1):

I checked `productloader2.php` which has `main.js` and same code you have posted here. This will create an infinite loop of `product` being called by every load of `productloader2.php`. You would better remove `main.js` in `productloader2.php`. You could use JSON to grab prodcuts.

```
product();

function product(){
    $.ajax({
        url :   "productloader2.php",
        method: "POST",
        data    :   {getProduct:1},
        success :   function(data){
            $("#get_product").html(data);
        },
        complete: function() {
            setTimeout(product, 10000000000000);
        }
    });
}
```

Here's a flow chart of happens

1. `products.php` calls `product()` is for first time (and registers interval)
2. `productloader2.php` is loaded
3. `product()` is called from `productloader2.php` (first time and registers interval).
4. `productloader2.php` is loaded from `productloader2.php` of **2**. and calls `product()` again and the loop continues.

Eventually, the page might crash.

Answer (score 0):

When ajax request complete it executes `setTimeout(product, 10000);` which then call product function again after 10000ms.

Comment: show me detail example what you want to do or paste your final code please

Comment: This is my productloader2.php which should load the products out of the db and ajax should make the post request to retrieve this info

Comment: U can find my ajax script at buycheapvaporizer.com/main.js

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  product();

  function product(){
    $.ajax({
      url :   "productloader2.php",
      method: "POST",
      data    :   {getProduct:1},
      success :   function(data){
        $("#get_product").html(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: you need only this

Comment: Still keeps refreshing

Comment: check whether you are calling the product() function anywhere else

Comment: or you should clear cache by hard reloading your page ctr + shif + r